# How do I remove whitespaces?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with a lot of special characters and multiple spaces. One column in particular has a lot of white spaces.

It looks like this:

[image]

so I did this:

```
def remove_whitespace(strings):
    x = strings.replace(" ", "")
    return x

df['Clean'] = df[0].apply(remove_whitespace)
```

but nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you are working with pandas dataframe: then probably you should try , `df['newcol'] = df['column'].str.replace(r'\s+','', regex=True)`, for a vanila python , `import re` ; `re.sub(r'\s+','',input_string)`

Comment: @beapbeep use applymap as i did in solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is something wrong with your code. Your function is getting an argument and in your case you are not passing a value for it.

```
def remove_whitespace(strings):
    x = strings.replace(" ", "")
    return x

df['Clean'] = df[0].apply(remove_whitespace(strings))
```

**Apply this solution:**

Apply our function to each element in our dataframe - use **applymap**.

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if type(x)==str else x)
```

**You can try this too**

```
def remove(string): 
    return "".join(string.split()) 

string = ' s t r i n  g'
print(remove(string))
```

**Output:**

```
string
```

Use the **`split()`** function to return a list of the words in the string. Then use **`join()`** to concatenate the iterable.